# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, typeerror

```
mixed = [1, 4, 'd']
if type(i) == int:
    for i in mixed:
        print([i ** 2])
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that what you want to do is:

```
mixed = [1,4,'d']

for i in mixed:
    if type(i) == int:
        print([i ** 2])
```