# problem passing public key into rsa decoder TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Good Day Everybody! is there a way to solve the decoding problem after passing the keys, the code working fine with encrypted and decrypted but once i start select the publick key from data base shows me this problem. i have change the data type everything good different error in same line **plain = [chr(pow(char ** key) % n) for char in ciphertext]** the error im getting **TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'int'**

Suppose the data from database is

```
data=16502916241650364826125871181879125871246803291624295583281818234716503551129558335511291624181879181879246803125871295583304595291624291624181879295583181496181496184182295114292940

key=117535
n=365867
private_key=113503
p=643
q=569
```

it's suppose to give me out put this:
**b7bcd0d379f2b5957003d947709¢Ó**

the decryption code :

```
def decrypt(nn,pk, ciphertext):
    #Unpack the key into its components

    n=nn
    key=pk
    #Generate the plaintext based on the ciphertext and key using a^b mod m
    plain = [chr((ord(char) ** key) % n) for char in ciphertext]
    #Return the array of bytes as a string
    return ''.join(plain)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    '''
    Detect if the script is being run directly by the user
    '''

    print("Your public key is ", public ," and your private key is ", private)

      msg1=name 

xxc=decrypt(n, key, msg1)
    print(xxc)
    print("\n")
```

**in the end i'm sending the result of  encrypted name is enc_name) and the public pair key picc and picc2**

i have try change the data type of pk1=int(231761) and pk2=int(399089) but not working at all, and try for str also same problem. i have seen several posts of same related problem but the solution not working in same my case , such like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17056264/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-or-pow-str-and-int) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52809152/typeerrorunsupported-operand-types-for-or-pow-str-and-int) and[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59919699/typeerrorunsupported-operand-types-for-or-pow-str-and-int) and[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45911338/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-or-pow-str-and-int) and[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41070988/python-3-typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-or-pow-str-and-int) none of these solutions are working with me. i'm using `python 3.6 spyder`

Any suggestion! thanks all

Comment: To improve your  RSA code, you may ask it CodeReview.SE, since it is working now. And don't forget to upvote and accept if the answers are useful and correct. This way people can see that your problem is solved with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`char` variable is string, so you need to convert it to int first. You can use [`ord()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) function for this:

```
plain = [chr((ord(char) ** key)  % n) for char in ciphertext]
```

Comment: thanks sir, but now im getting this error 'TypeError: pow expected at least 2 arguments, got 1' ?? even im passing two arguments public and msg1

Comment: @honey `pow()` needs two arguments a base and power

Comment: maybe you want this `chr(pow(ord(char), key) % n)`

Comment: @Shubham Shaswat if i change it to this, im getting wrong decryption data at all

Comment: @honey you should use or `pow` or `**` not both at the same time.

Comment: ya sir you right, i have remove the pow, and use ** still getting wrong decryption data, i will try post the full code there that can see where the problem come

Comment: @honey `chr()` need to have an value which can be map to an ascii,what is your `n` here

Comment: @honey looks like problem in encryption function,  you should change it according to decription. Or probably you have incorrect keypair.

Comment: i have update the code all, what i need to do is, divide the code into two part, one encrypted and second one decrypted, the code is working good in this way but when i pass the encrypted data to data base with the public keys, im getting different in decryption part, look to the code

Comment: @neverwalkaloner and Shubham Shaswat i have update the full code, take look and i need to devide it into two parts , one for encrypted and second decrypted

Comment: @honey there are lot of code. Try to debug it using pdb (https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) or your IDE debug tool.

Comment: the code is working fine sir , i have test it already , but i dont know why decryption part give different result even im passing same public pair key, its require to pass also n value?

Comment: @honey yes you should pass `n` value to encrypt and dectypt data.

Comment: ok sir, i think thats the problem i just pass only the public key, i will test it

Comment: same same, no change i was already pass the same n value and public key , getting wrong decryption